# Convergence of $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin x+1}{x^5} dx$

Tags: convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Does the integral $I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin x+1}{x^5} dx$ converge or diverge?

My try:

I have used integration by parts

$$\int \frac{\sin x+1}{x^5} dx=(\sin x+1) \int \frac{dx}{x^{5}}-\int(\cos x) \int \frac{dx}{x^{5}}dx$$

So
$$I=\left.\frac{(\sin x+1) x^{-4}}{-4}\right|_{0} ^{1}+\frac{1}{4} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\cos x}{x^{4}} d x=\infty+\frac{J}{4}$$

Finally irrespective of whether $J$ converges or diverges to infinity, $I$ diverges to infinity.

Is there a better approach?

Comment: Your argument works becuse $J$ cannot diverge to $-\infty$.

Comment: Yes thats what i mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sin(x) \ge 0$ on $[0,1]$ then
$$
\sin(x) +1 \ge 0 +1 = \max_{[0,1]}x \ge x 
$$
So $\sin(x) +1 \ge x $ on $[0,1]$, and thus
$$
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sin x+1}{x^5} \mathrm{d}x \ge \int_{0}^{1}\frac{x}{x^5}\mathrm{d}x  
$$
and the latter diverges since $\frac{1}{x^3} \to \infty$ as $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\sin(x)+1\geq 0+1=1$?

Comment: @Gary, thank you for pointing out the mistake. I've corrected the argument in an edit.